# How to use MDB3 with webpack?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, npm, webpack, material-design

I want to use Material design for bootstrap3, [mdb3](https://mdbootstrap.com/mdb3/getting-started-mdb3/) in my app using webpack, but not able to find any npm repo for the same, could anyone help me about how to use it ? Should I use the CDN along with the installed modules or is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try next package :
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-bootstrap-md